# How to set an environment variable when using system() to execute a command?

Tags: c, linux, system

I'm writing a C program on Linux and need to execute a command with `system()`, and need to set an environment variable when executing that command, but I don't know how to set the env var when using `system()`.

Comment: *system("var=val cmd")* doesn't that work?

Comment: The argument to `system` is just a shell command line. So you set it the same way you would in the shell.

Comment: $ EXAMPLE=test env|grep EXAMPLE -->
EXAMPLE=test --> This seems to work in shell...

Answer (score 5):

If you want to pass an environment variable to your child process that is different from the parent, you can use a combination of [`getenv`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv) and [`setenv`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setenv). Say, you want to pass a different `PATH` to your child:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *oldenv = strdup(getenv("PATH")); // Make a copy of your PATH
    setenv("PATH", "hello", 1); // Overwrite it

    system("echo $PATH"); // Outputs "hello"

    setenv("PATH", oldenv, 1); // Restore old PATH
    free(oldenv); // Don't forget to free!

    system("echo $PATH"); // Outputs your actual PATH
}
```

Otherwise, if you're just creating a new environment variable, you can use a combination of [`setenv`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setenv) and [`unsetenv`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/unsetenv), like this:

```
int main() {
    setenv("SOMEVAR", "hello", 1); // Create environment variable
    system("echo $SOMEVAR"); // Outputs "hello"
    unsetenv("SOMEVAR"); // Clear that variable (optional)
}
```

And don't forget to check for error codes, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setenv()` api for setting environment variables in Linux

```
#include <stdlib.h>  
int setenv(const char *envname, const char *envval, int overwrite);
```

Refer to http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/setenv/ for more information.

After setting environment variables using `setenv()` use `system()` to execute any command.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    system("EXAMPLE=test env|grep EXAMPLE");
}
```

outputs

> EXAMPLE=test

Comment: I like this method as it does not spoil the existing environment in the parent (i.e. if you call `system()` multiple times, you may want to define various variables but may not to see the variables you defined for a given call in the other calls!)

Comment: This does not work on Pre-POSIX Bourne shells